# How do state of the art echo cancellation algorithms deal with variable propagation times of sound due to multiple speakers or reverberation?

Tags: adaptive-filters, multipath

I understand how echo cancellation works with a single speaker and no reverberation (using adaptive filtering and freezing the coefficients during double-talk). However, in cases with more than one speaker source or reverberation causing different propagation of the same signal, would this not completely change the combined signal and cause issues with the ability to cancel the echo? Thanks in advance!

Comment: multiple microphones and beamforming would help